# A generic complex contour integral

Tags: causality, complex-numbers, calculus, analyticity

If, let's say, I have an integral such as
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{dt}{(t-a)(t-b)(t-c)(t-d)}$$
where $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ are complex numbers such that the poles falls in all the four quadrant and $t$ is time.

Now to do the integral what contour should I choose?
Also which poles should I keep inside the contour and which should I keep outside so that causality is maintained?

I know for the case when we have an exponential in the denominator we generally choose the contour considering the side for which the exponential decays to 0.

Though it is a very general problem but is there any way to tackle them?
For this problem, it seems all the possible combination of poles stays inside or outside the contour would produce different results.

Some help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried closing the contour either above or below and seeing what happens?

Comment: I tried ML inequality, for both the contour it came out to be decaying at large R. But I did not know which pole to keep inside.

Comment: As the integration contour are generally determined by physical context they appear, this problem seems to be not well-formed.

Comment: @Sayan: I think you can choose which pole you include. If a and b are in the upper plane and c and d in the lower, then when closing the pole from above, use a and b. You could check by trying both. (I don't know if it is correct ;))

Comment: @Sayan: do you understand my answer. If not, I can expand on it

Comment: @Sayan: can you access the chat?

Comment: @Sayan: if my answer helped you, accept + upvote. If not, tell me what you want to know more ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can choose a contour by closing from above or below (and show that in the limit of large radius, the contribution of the circle vanishes), excluding the poles at a, b, c and d. Use the Residue Theorem (just calculate simple derivatives, instead of integrating by parts). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem.

Comment: If i exclude all the poles then wouldn't the integration becomes zero .

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Integration around a closed loop (and thus without poles) gives zero.

Comment: @Sayan: that's the art of complex integration! Of course, for other cases like with a logarithm, you should be aware of branch cuts etc... Try it and if you have any question tell me

Comment: So are you saying that the integration mentioned in the question has an output 0.

Comment: No, because you have 4 poles a, b, c and d

Comment: The fraction in the integral, call it f(t). Calculate the derivatives of the f(t) at the poles (the ones relevant, for example, the poles which are in the contour) and add those with a factor -2pi*i

Comment: $\int f(t) dt = 2*\pi*i*sum_{poles} Res_{t = pole}f(t)$

Comment: And the residue, for first-order poles as in this case, is $lim_{t->pole} f(t)(t-pole)$ I guess. Will check in a minute

Comment: @Sayan: So, in your case for pole a, the residue becomes 1/(a-b)(a-c)(a-d).

Comment: @Sayan: do you see the similarity with the other answer. Except that there is no log.

Comment: Yes I have all the residues, calculated. But I was not sure which poles to take and which to leave. I tried ml inequality and both the contour vanishes for large R. My question is, if a logical argument can be drawn to choose the contour from causality principle

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134352/discussion-between-mrq-and-sayan).

Comment: @Sayan: See the chat